# Unable to sync with device - Arduino Nano rosserial

Tags: arduino, ros-melodic, rosserial-arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I am trying to use rosserial to communicate between a Jetson Nano 2GB and Arduino Nano.

Here is my error:
`[ERROR] [1624844028.297385]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino`

I have already tried the suggestions in [this forum post](https://answers.ros.org/question/210875/arduino-rosserial-unable-to-sync-with-device/?next=/question/210875/arduino-rosserial-unable-to-sync-with-device/) such as changing the baud rate on both ends, different cable, etc. I am only subscribing to one topic from the Arduino Nano.

I am new to ROS, so any help is appreciated. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381240/unable-to-sync-with-device---arduino-nano-rosserial/) by [MiPlayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/76755/miplayer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been able to resolve the issue. The issue is due to the Arduino Nano and the limited 'bandwidth'. Bandwith may not be the right word, but the Nano is not able to handle it. An Arduino Mega will resolve the issue and I have tried the Teensy 4.0, and with a modified ros_lib library, it seems to have solved the issue.

---

Originally posted by [MiPlayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/76755/miplayer/) with karma: 26 on 2021-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0